# Running multiple instance of an online game

Tags: windows-7

My problem is I want to run two instances of an application. I have tried Sandboxie, which Google has given me, but it failed on my part. The application is an online game. Can anyone please help?.

I'm running Windows 7 and the game can be found at http://weapon.ph.

Comment: Which online game is it? That might help.

Comment: @PeterK - it's here, [weapons of war](http://weapon.ph)

Answer (score 2):

See on Super User: [Run multiple instance of any windows application](https://superuser.com/questions/165937/run-multiple-instance-of-any-windows-application) and [Running Multiple Instances of the Same Application in Vista](https://superuser.com/questions/43037/running-multiple-instances-of-the-same-application-in-vista).

It's a "per application" thing. Some programs will check the process list and prevent you from doing that anyway. It seems to be the case with this game.

One way would be to use a [virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine), but it might me too much of a hassle, then.

Comment: Remember the game could also be using further mechanisms to prevent multiple "instances", like limiting one login per IP address.

Comment: @Gnoupi, thanks but I have tried already all your suggestions with no luck. I guess it can't be done with this one.

Comment: @Reigel - the VM too? If so, it could be a "unique IP" block like badp suggest.

Comment: @Gnoupi yeah... VM triggers an alert that says "sorry this can't be run on a virtual machine".

Comment: @Reigel - if there is such kind of protection to even detect a VM, it means they really made everything to prevent people from duplicating the process. I'm sorry, I think you're out of luck here.

Comment: @Reigel: A program should not be able to detect if it's being run in a VM - if it can, it means there's a security vulnerability in the VM!  Any such protection would have to be VM-specific - have you tried any others?  There are [lots of VMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_platform_virtual_machines) - try [VMWare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Workstation) or [Virtual PC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Virtual_PC)

Comment: @ [BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/2578/blueraja-danny-pflughoeft) and yes the game did detect it was inside a VM...

Answer (score 2):

Some games, such as Dark Age of Camelot allow for multiple instances to run on one machine (although they need to be the same realm/faction).  It's an inherent part of the game's functionality (see buffbots).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a spare pc, but want to run the programs on the same machine, you could use a remote client like VNC and use the spare computer as a headless host. Then you might still need to proxy the IP traffic, since it would still be coming from the same internet connection.

You might try using an alternate browser that runs through proxy servers, though this probably won't work for a Java game if it is matching process ids.